# Getting 'cannot add foreign key constraint' error

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: (using `MySQL`)
`User` and `Profile`.

`User` has the following column:

```
Name: reqid
Type: char(36)
Null: NO
Key: PRI
```

and `Profile` has:

```
Name: reqid
Type: char(36)
Null: NO
```

But when I try to execute the following:

```
ALTER TABLE Profile ADD CONSTRAINT fk_req
    FOREIGN KEY (reqid ) REFERENCES User ( reqid ) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I get the `cannot add foreign key constraint` error.

Why is that? Both columns are of the same type.

Comment: Does table Profile have reqid column values in it that are not present in table User reqid column?

Comment: @J2112Oyes it does.

Comment: Without seeing any data in your tables, I feel that is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-errors):

> Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the
>   central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing
>   back to its parent.

make sure column `reqid` in both tables (`Profile` and `User`) contain **identical values**.

Comment: For some reason even after clearing all records from both tables i still get the error..

Comment: Can you provide SHOW CREATE TABLE output for both tables in your original post?

Comment: I noticed these columns are different in their character set. Also, one of them has a constraint of `NOT NULL` and the other one doesn't. Without that constraint applied, it wouldn't be possible to link them?

Comment: Yes their character sets must match (if they are nonbinary strings). Also, as suggested in other answers, are you escaping the word User in the create table statement?

Comment: Yes i am. But do their constraints must much as well? (`NOT NULL`)

Comment: I am not 100% sure but it very well may. Since no ON UPDATE subclause is specified, I believe the default is RESTRICT.

Comment: I don't think the `NOT NULL` constraint was a problem.
As soon as i changed the characters set it worked, thanks!

Comment: Making sure they both had the same character set, which was not the case.

Answer (score 0):

`User` is a keyword and should be escaped like below. Moreover, make sure `User` table do exists already before you execute this statement

```
ALTER TABLE Profile ADD CONSTRAINT fk_req
    FOREIGN KEY (reqid ) REFERENCES `User` ( reqid ) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: @Gambit2007 do check if you already have a FK constraint on that column?

Comment: Hmm how can i do that?

Comment: Doesn't look like such constraint exists.